# Renaming all files in a folder with python using specific condition

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a folder which has files with names:
`"fileX.JPG"  where X = 1....N`
and I want to name the files as :
`"000000000X.JPG" where X=1...N`

The new name of the file should have the number from the old name of the file plus the zeros. so example file names I want is:

```
0000000000001.jpg
0000000000011.jpg
0000000000111.jpg
```

etc

The file name is 13 characters long. so should have zeros accordingly.

I have not started my code. Don't know where should I start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.rename()` from the os module

Answer (score 0):

```
for path in pathlib.Path("a_directory").iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        old_name = path.stem
#original filename


        old_extension = path.suffix
#original file extension
```

Also try this:

```
import os
path = '/Users/myName/Desktop/directory'
files = os.listdir(path)


for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(index), '.jpg'])))

        directory = path.parent
#current file location

        new_name = "text" + old_name + old_extension

        path.rename(pathlib.Path(directory, new_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.rename`.
For example:

```
for file in os.listdir():
    # Get the number, e.g.:
    old_number = file.strip("file")[1].strip(".JPG")[0]
    os.rename(file, f"{old_number}.JPG")
```

You might have to adapt based on how your files are actually namd

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
  
# Function to rename multiple files 
def main(): 
  
    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("path-to-files")): 
        
        d = str(count).zfill(12)
        dst = d + ".jpg"
        src ='path-to-file'+ filename 
        dst ='path-to-file'+ dst 
          
        # rename() function will 
        # rename all the files 
        os.rename(src, dst) 
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
      
    # Calling main() function 
    main()
```